# How to implement the slowly updating side inputs in python

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am attempting to implement the `slowly updating global window side inputs` example from the [documentation](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/patterns/side-inputs/#slowly-updating-global-window-side-inputs) from java into python and I am kinda stuck on what the `AfterProcessingTime.pastFirstElementInPane()` equivalent in python. For the `map` I've done something like this:

```py
class ApiKeys(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, elm) -> Iterable[Dict[str, str]]:
        yield TimestampedValue(
            {"<api_key_1>": "<account_id_1>", "<api_key_2>": "<account_id_2>",},
            elm,
        )

map = beam.pvalue.AsSingleton(
    p
    | "trigger pipeline" >> beam.Create([None])
    | "define schedule"
    >> beam.Map(
        lambda _: (
            0,  # would be timestamp.Timestamp.now() in production
            20, # would be timestamp.MAX_TIMESTAMP in production
            1,  # would be around 1 hour or so in production
        )
    )
    | "GenSequence"
    >> PeriodicSequence()
    | "ApplyWindowing"
    >> beam.WindowInto(
        beam.window.GlobalWindows(),
        trigger=Repeatedly(Always(), AfterProcessingTime(???)),
        accumulation_mode=AccumulationMode.DISCARDING,
    )
    | "api_keys" >> beam.ParDo(ApiKeys())
)
```

I am hoping to use this as a `Dict[str, str]` input to a downstream function that will have windows of 60 seconds, merging with this one that I hope to update on an hourly basis.

The point is to run this on google cloud dataflow (where we currently just re-release it to update the `api_keys`).

I've pasted the java example from the documentation below for convenience sake:

```java
public static void sideInputPatterns() {
  // This pipeline uses View.asSingleton for a placeholder external service.
  // Run in debug mode to see the output.
  Pipeline p = Pipeline.create();

  // Create a side input that updates each second.
  PCollectionView<Map<String, String>> map =
      p.apply(GenerateSequence.from(0).withRate(1, Duration.standardSeconds(5L)))
          .apply(
              Window.<Long>into(new GlobalWindows())
                  .triggering(Repeatedly.forever(AfterProcessingTime.pastFirstElementInPane()))
                  .discardingFiredPanes())
          .apply(
              ParDo.of(
                  new DoFn<Long, Map<String, String>>() {

                    @ProcessElement
                    public void process(
                        @Element Long input, OutputReceiver<Map<String, String>> o) {
                      // Replace map with test data from the placeholder external service.
                      // Add external reads here.
                      o.output(PlaceholderExternalService.readTestData());
                    }
                  }))
          .apply(View.asSingleton());

  // Consume side input. GenerateSequence generates test data.
  // Use a real source (like PubSubIO or KafkaIO) in production.
  p.apply(GenerateSequence.from(0).withRate(1, Duration.standardSeconds(1L)))
      .apply(Window.into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardSeconds(1))))
      .apply(Sum.longsGlobally().withoutDefaults())
      .apply(
          ParDo.of(
                  new DoFn<Long, KV<Long, Long>>() {

                    @ProcessElement
                    public void process(ProcessContext c) {
                      Map<String, String> keyMap = c.sideInput(map);
                      c.outputWithTimestamp(KV.of(1L, c.element()), Instant.now());

                      LOG.debug(
                          "Value is {}, key A is {}, and key B is {}.",
                          c.element(),
                          keyMap.get("Key_A"),
                          keyMap.get("Key_B"));
                    }
                  })
              .withSideInputs(map));
}

/** Placeholder class that represents an external service generating test data. */
public static class PlaceholderExternalService {

  public static Map<String, String> readTestData() {

    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    Instant now = Instant.now();

    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("HH:MM:SS");

    map.put("Key_A", now.minus(Duration.standardSeconds(30)).toString(dtf));
    map.put("Key_B", now.minus(Duration.standardSeconds(30)).toString());

    return map;
  }
}
```

Any ideas as to how to emulate this example would be enormously appreciated, I've spent literally days on this issue now :(

**Update #2 based on @AlexanderMoraes**

So, I've tried changing it according to my understanding of your suggestions:

```py
        main_window_size = 5
        trigger_interval = 30
        side_input = beam.pvalue.AsSingleton(
            p
            | "trigger pipeline" >> beam.Create([None])
            | "define schedule"
            >> beam.Map(
                lambda _: (
                    0,  # timestamp.Timestamp.now().__float__(),
                    60,  # timestamp.Timestamp.now().__float__() + 30.0,
                    trigger_interval,  # fire_interval
                )
            )
            | "GenSequence" >> PeriodicSequence()
            | "api_keys" >> beam.ParDo(ApiKeys())
            | "window"
            >> beam.WindowInto(
                beam.window.GlobalWindows(),
                trigger=Repeatedly(AfterProcessingTime(window_size)),
                accumulation_mode=AccumulationMode.DISCARDING,
            )        
        )
```

But when combining this with another pipeline with windowing set to something smaller than `trigger_interval` I am unable to use the dictionary as a singleton because for some reason they are duplicated:

```sh
ValueError: PCollection of size 2 with more than one element accessed as a singleton view. First two elements encountered are "{'<api_key_1>': '<account_id_1>', '<api_key_2>': '<account_id_2>'}", "{'<api_key_1>': '<account_id_1>', '<api_key_2>': '<account_id_2>'}". [while running 'Pair with AccountIDs']
```

Is there some way to clarify that the singleton output should ignore whatever came before it?

Answer (score 1):

The title of the question *"slowly updating side inputs"* refers to the [documentation](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/patterns/side-inputs/#slowly-updating-side-input-using-windowing), which already has a Python version of the code. However, the code you provided is from "updating global window side inputs", which just has the Java version for the code. So I will be addressing an answer for the second one.

You are not able to reproduce the `AfterProcessingTime.pastFirstElementInPane()` within Python. This function is used to fire triggers, which determine when to emit results of each window (refered as pane). In your case, this particular call `AfterProcessingTime.pastFirstElementInPane()` creates a trigger that fires when the current processing time passes the processing time at which this trigger saw the first element in a pane, [here](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.0.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/windowing/AfterProcessingTime.html#:%7E:text=pastFirstElementInPane,-public%20static%20AfterProcessingTime&text=AfterProcessingTime%20pastFirstElementInPane()-,Creates%20a%20trigger%20that%20fires%20when%20the%20current%20processing%20time,first%20element%20in%20a%20pane). In Python this is achieve using `AfterWatermark` and `AfterProcessingTime()`.

Below, there are two pieces of code one in Java and another one in Python. Thus, you can understand more about each one's usage. Both examples set a time-based trigger which emits results one minute after the first element of the window has been processed. Also, the accumulation mode is set for not accumulating the results (***Java**: discardingFiredPanes() and **Python**: accumulation_mode=AccumulationMode.DISCARDING*).

**1-** *Java*:

```
 PCollection<String> pc = ...;
  pc.apply(Window.<String>into(FixedWindows.of(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES))
                               .triggering(AfterProcessingTime.pastFirstElementInPane()
                                                              .plusDelayOf(Duration.standardMinutes(1)))
                               .discardingFiredPanes());
```

**2-** *Python*: the trigger configuration is the same as described in point **1**

```
pcollection | WindowInto(
    FixedWindows(1 * 60),
    trigger=AfterProcessingTime(1 * 60),
    accumulation_mode=AccumulationMode.DISCARDING)
```

The examples above were taken from thew [documentation](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#setting-a-trigger).

Comment: Hi Alexander! Thank you so much for looking at it. I tried your suggestions and have updated my original post with how I understood it and the issue I encountered with using it

Comment: And yes, I was hoping to do the global windowed values for the api keys, such that I can just refresh them every hour or so, independent of the main enrichment going on.

Comment: @Paddie, I don't think you need to use `AfterAny(AfterWatermark()` , instead you could use `Repeatedly(AfterProcessingTime(main_window_size))`.  So it will emit the results repeatedly after the specified processing time.

Comment: @alexander: something like this? 

`beam.WindowInto(beam.window.GlobalWindows(), trigger=Repeatedly(AfterProcessingTime(window_size)),accumulation_mode=AccumulationMode.DISCARDING)` ? Should the accumulation_mode not be accumulating instead such that I keep outputting the same value?

Comment: I updated the update - I am still seeing the same error though :(

Comment: @Paddie, as I understand, your passing your side inputs as singleton. There is an know issue with this, [here](https://www.mail-archive.com/user@beam.apache.org/msg02129.html). It mentions that you should use View.asMultimap(), in Java, that  will mean each trigger firing for a key will add a new element to the set of values for a key.

Comment: Furthermore, within the documentation, [here](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/transforms/python/elementwise/map/#example-6-map-with-side-inputs-as-singletons), it explains how to pass the side input as a singletons. Since you had an value error, I believe that your map as singleton might be wrong. Since, I can not reproduce your case, I suggest you to follow the example in this [link](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/transforms/python/elementwise/map/#example-6-map-with-side-inputs-as-singletons). Did it help you?

Comment: those are definitely better examples than I was working off-of before. Thank you! I'll try to revisit my branch (I've since had to just cache the API call in a DoFn for 1 hour, but that kinda caches it in all the works that are executing the DoFn I suppose).

I'll report back later if that worked!

Comment: @Paddie, I am glad to know that was what you were looking for. Please, if you found the information useful, consider **upvoting** and **accepting** the answer.

Answer (score 1):

AsIter() insted of AsSingleton() worked for me