# Slowly updating global window side inputs In Python

Tags: python, apache-beam

I try to get the updating sideinputs working in python as stated in the Documentation (there is only a java example provided) [https://beam.apache.org/documentation/patterns/side-inputs/]

I already found this thread here on Stackoverflow: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63812879/how-to-implement-the-slowly-updating-side-inputs-in-python] and tried the code and solution from there...

But when I try:

```
 pipeline
            | "generate sequence" >> PeriodicImpulse(0,90,30)
            | beam.WindowInto(
                GlobalWindows(),
                trigger=Repeatedly(AfterProcessingTime(1*30)),
                accumulation_mode=AccumulationMode.DISCARDING
            )
            | beam.Map(lambda _: print("fired"))
        )
```

There are 3 events fired as expected... the only thing is that those 3 events are fired instant and not every 30 seconds as I would be expecting.

To get it working I'm currently don't use it as a sideinput but just run it in pytest via:

```
def test_updating_sideinput():
    pipeline = beam.Pipeline()
    res = (
        pipeline
        | "generate sequence" >> PeriodicImpulse(0, 90, 30)
        | beam.Map(lambda _: print("fired"))
        | beam.WindowInto(
            GlobalWindows(),
            trigger=Repeatedly(AfterProcessingTime(1*30)),
            accumulation_mode=AccumulationMode.DISCARDING
        )
    )
    pipeline.run()
```

What would be the correct way to have a sideInput Updated triggered periodically using python?

thanks and regards

Answer (score 2):

The reason why all of the elements from `PeriodicImpulse` are emitted at the same time is because of the parameters you use when creating the transform. The documentation of the transform states that the arguments `start_timestamp` and `stop_timestamp` are timestamps, and (despite the documentation not stating that), `interval` is then interpreted as a number of seconds.

Since the implementation of `PeriodicImpulse` is based on Splittable DoFn with `OffsetRange`, every time a single output is processed, the remainder of all (future) outputs is deferred to later time, which is specified by the current timestamp + interval. This causes all the deferred timestamps generated to be in the past (lower than `Timestamp.now()`), therefore triggering processing of the remainder immediately. You can see the implementation in https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.32.0/_modules/apache_beam/transforms/periodicsequence.html#ImpulseSeqGenDoFn.

Using `Timestamp`s instead of absolute numbers in `PeriodicImpulse` should solve your problem.

```py
start = Timestamp.now()
stop = now + Duration(seconds=60)
...
pipeline
| "generate sequence" >> PeriodicImpulse(start, stop, 30)
```

But keep in mind once you are using a runner, `Timestamp.now()` is called when constructing the pipeline, and by the time the pipeline is executed, may already be well in the past, possibly triggering several minutes worth of data immediately.

Also note that `PeriodicImpulse` already supports windowing into `FixedWindows` based on the `inverval` param.